# Past perfect and present perfect

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect

Are the following sentences correct?

1) They were dating for the longest time but then they broke up, because she cheated on him.

2) I've gone grocery shopping this morning.

3) I had never thought about it vs I have never thought about it. (which one is correct and why)

4) When I introduced my dad to my friend, they just laughed, and said they had already met each other/they have already met each other. (the second option sounds correct to me, but I would use present perfect rather than past perfect)

If there is the possibility to use both, please write some examples. It would be really really helpful.

Comment: You have more than one question here, methinks.  Your (1) has no perfect tense at all...

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, but mildly colloquial. Also acceptable & equivalent in meaning: "They dated for the longest time..."
2. Slightly odd with no context, but acceptable. More normal would be "I went grocery shopping...", or "I've *already* gone grocery shopping this morning", or as part of a list: "I've gone grocery shopping, washed the dog, and mowed the lawn this morning."
3. Both are correct. They have different implications

   "I had never thought about it... until now." The use of past tense indicates that conditions have changed. The "not thinking" is only in the past.

   "I have never thought about it" means that you didn't think in the past, and you're still not thinking.
4. It would be normal in the moment to say "we've met". But when you're relating a previous incident, you would say "they said they had already met"